# What are the common errors you see when you run 'java -cp ...' or 'java -classpath'? How do you set a directory of jars in classpath?

Tags: java, classpath

When you run 'java -cp ...' or 'java -classpath'?
How do you set a directory of jars in classpath?

In Linux, java -cp /some/directory/ would not work!
although it clearly says directory in -cp is supported.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html

Comment: What's in that directory?

Comment: Are you not trying to run some Java program at the same time? Have you tried doing `java -cp /some/directory/with/classes com.example.MyProgram.java`?